# Google spreadsheet change label

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to figure out how to do this. I wish to Print out a column name and below the result. Here is a simple query i wrote in google spreadsheet:

```
=query(A:F, "SELECT COUNT(A) WHERE A = 'CORE' OR A = 'TRIAL'")
```

However, the result looks like this:

count
37

What I would like it to look like is:

Total
37

Now, in normal SQL I would just say:

```
=query(A:F, "SELECT COUNT(A) AS 'Total' WHERE A = 'CORE' OR A = 'TRIAL'")
```

However, that doesn't seem to work here. I have tried using the label function, but it just generates error every time.

```
=query(A:F, "SELECT COUNT(A) LABEL COUNT(A) 'Total' WHERE A = 'CORE' OR A = 'TRIAL'")
```

I am looking for either a way to force it to print the result in the cell the formula is written in (as right now it prints it on next row) or for me to somehow change the label

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works

```
=query(A:F, "SELECT COUNT(A) WHERE A = 'CORE' OR A = 'TRIAL' LABEL COUNT(A) ''")
```

Or use the formulas I provided in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63276791/google-spreadsheet-countifs-not-respecting-or-condition).