# Google spreadsheet countifs not respecting or condition

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have the following formula:

```
=COUNTIFS(A2:A41, {"CORE", "TRIAL"})
```

However, the count comes as 7 when it should be 10. There are 7 core and 3 trials. Is there something I am missing? Just for testing, I tried putting TRIAL as first and it counted 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your formula to

```
=sum(ArrayFormula(COUNTIF(A2:A41, {"CORE", "TRIAL"})))
```

or use

```
=sumproduct(regexmatch(A2:A41, "CORE|TRIAL"))
```

If you only want exact matches, use

```
=sumproduct(regexmatch(A2:A41, "^CORE|TRIAL$"))
```

See if that helps?